# How to make div properly contain (inside of its border) floated elements?

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't div properly contain floated elements(with `float` property specified `left` or `right`)

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <button style="float: right; padding: 10px;">this is button</button>
</div>
```

How do I make the div properly contain (inside of its border) this floated element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `overflow: auto` on your div, it expands the div according to its content.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto">
    <button style="float: right; padding: 10px;">this is button</button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jMshh/

Here is a tutorial which explains in detail how the overflow works: 
http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your floats otherwise the container will collapse to zero height. There are numerous ways to do this. Here is one example:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <button style="float: right; padding: 10px;">this is button</button>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use :-  `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <button style="float: right; padding: 10px;">this is button</button>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow: hidden` for parent div.

Answer (score 0):

use the clear fix

```
.clear:after, .clear:before {
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jMshh/